# Dropbox SDK has missing CSRF token on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, dropbox

Using the official Ruby Dropbox SDK (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ruby), I have a problem that only occurs on production.

I use the following code in my Rails 4.1.8 application to generate an authorization url to connect with Dropbox:

```
def dropbox_web_auth()
  DropboxOAuth2Flow.new ENV['DROPBOX_API_KEY'], ENV['DROPBOX_API_SECRET'],
    authorize_account_dropbox_index_url, session, :dropbox_auth_csrf_token
end
```

This works. Both on development and production it generates an authorization URL which makes it possible to connect with Dropbox. But after I get redirected to my app I'm getting a `DropboxOAuth2Flow::BadStateError` error: `Missing CSRF token in session.`

I run a production server behind Cloudflare with Cloudflare's SSL enabled. I first suspected this would be a caching thing because my Evernote Oauth connection also fails (which doesn't give an error whatsoever), but purging the Cloudflare cache and putting the website in Development Mode wouldn't help.

I suspect the error could have something to do with using ReactJS/Ajax. I'm doing an Ajax call from a React Component to a method that checks if the user has authorization. If not, it generates the authorization url:

```
if current_user.customer.dropbox_access_token
  begin
    dropbox_client().account_info
  rescue
    @authorization_url = dropbox_web_auth().start()
  end
else
  @authorization_url = dropbox_web_auth().start()
end
```

`@authorization_url` gets passed back to the React Component which renders the URL. Because this call is handled by an Ajax call, the Ajax call sets the session with CSRF token but the user on the page doesn't yet have access to the just set CSRF token – only on a hard page refresh (but then the Ajax call would generate a new CSRF token which renders the previous useless).

PS: I'm using an Ajax call because this way I can do an Ajax call per API which doesn't bottlenecks my app by having to wait for all API authorization checks to finish.

Comment: My guess would be that the session is somehow not being preserved between requests. Where is the session being persisted? Are you running on more than one server without centralized session storage?

Comment: @smarx That would be weird, because it would mean the Dropbox CSRF token is the only session key not being persisted – I have a bunch of default session variables always being in there. I'm running default Rails 4 session storage, so no weird things going on there.

Comment: I assume the exception is being raised in `DropboxOAuth2Flow.finish`, right? If so, it should only happen if the CSRF token is not present in the session: `csrf_token_from_session = @session[@csrf_token_session_key]` ... `if csrf_token_from_session.nil? raise BadStateError.new("Missing CSRF token in session.");` So double-check that the CSRF token really is there before you call `finish`.

Comment: @smarx well, that's exactly what's wrong right? The CSRF token is not present in the session – also not when the page is rendered with the authorization url. So I'll know it will fail, because for some reason the CSRF token isn't set in the session.

Comment: If you've confirmed that's what's wrong, then I'd continue simplifying. E.g. cut the Dropbox SDK out of the picture and just do `@session[:dropbox_auth_csrf_token] = 'HERE'` and then verify that it's disappearing from the session later. Then double-check that other session variables are truly being persisted between requests.